# Search by name with firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem several days ago and I don't find a solution.

I´m trying search in my firebase database by name but the result is always null.

The database is the next;

[image: database]

The code that I use is the next;

```
final String nombre = edtNombreJugador.getText().toString().trim().toUpperCase();

mDatabase.child("user").child("personalData").orderByChild("name").equalTo(nombre);

mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

String title = (String) singleSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
System.out.println("TITLE: "+title);


 }
```

Title always return null in my case.

Can somebody help me please? I don't know what I'm doing bad...

Comment: Since you're converting the text to all-uppercase, it doesn't match the mixed-case content. To solve this problem, either require the user to perform exact-case matches or store the all-uppercase text in an additional property. We just resolved a quite similar question earlier today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44264337/i-am-trying-to-perform-a-search-on-names-within-my-firebaserecycleradapter-with Searching in Firebase is case-sensitive.

Comment: I think that the problem is not the uppercase. In my database, the value of attribute name is only in capital letters. My code for search is correct for that database?

Comment: Ah, I see. There's a typo in there. You code loads `user `, while your JSON has `users` (with an `s` at the end).

Comment: Yeah, it was an error. I would be 'users' but the result its the same, null. I dont know why...

Comment: it works! Thank you Frank!

Comment: I can't click in upvote button because I have less than 15 reputation. Checkmark yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now you're querying the database path `/user/personalData`. And then for each child node under there, you're comparing the `name` property to the value the user entered. So `/user/personalData/***/name`.

That doesn't match the path in the database, which is `/user/***/personalData/name`. To query that you do:

```
Query query = mDatabase.child("user").orderByChild("personalData/name").equalTo(nombre);

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {...
```

Comment: Great answer as always Frank.

Answer (score 0):

Im trying too with this code (more clear for me) for return all names in database but the result is null too:

```
 DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/");
 mDatabase.child("personalData");
  final UsersData[] user = {null};
  ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
         String title = (String) 
         postSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
          System.out.println("TITLE: "+title);
       }
     }
      @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
       Log.e("The read failed: " ,firebaseError.getMessage());
       }
    };
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```